# How to intercept messages between usb device and host controller?

Tags: usb, libusb-1.0

I have to write a usb over ethernet application. Using vhci - (http://sourceforge.net/projects/usb-vhci/?source=typ_redirect) I am able to create a virtual usb device. Now I need to intercept communication between actual device and server and redirect it over ip to the virtual device created on the client. I need help regarding this interception part.